# Why are my green pepper plant leaves deformed from the top?

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, chili

I live in Toronto, Canada. I have noticed some of the leaves of my Green chilli plant curling at the top, always towards the side. Also, some leaves are deformed. It would be great if you can help me out here. This is my first time trying my hand at gardening.[image]

Comment: I think something had a munch when the leaf was smaller. I don't see "curling" but very curly small (1cm or so) leaves could be due to aphids. Otherwise the other leaves look healthy!